# data.table residual variance for multiple factors and keys

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large 'data.table' composed of daily returns for multiple stocks.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(data.table)
set.seed(1080)
Firm1 <- rbind(data.table(Month = rep(200001, 3), Firm = rep(1, 3), Rt = rnorm(3)) ,data.table(Month = rep(200002, 4), Firm = rep(1, 4), Rt = rnorm(4)),
           data.table(Month = rep(200003, 5), Firm = rep(1, 5), Rt = rnorm(5)), data.table(Month = rep(200004, 2), Firm = rep(1, 2), Rt = rnorm(2)),
           data.table(Month = rep(200005, 3), Firm = rep(1, 3), Rt = rnorm(3)))
Firm2 <- rbind(data.table(Month = rep(200001, 1), Firm = rep(2, 1), Rt = rnorm(1)) , data.table(Month = rep(200002, 3), Firm = rep(2, 3), Rt = rnorm(3)),
           data.table(Month = rep(200003, 4), Firm = rep(2, 4), Rt = rnorm(4)), data.table(Month = rep(200004, 1), Firm = rep(2, 1), Rt = rnorm(1)),
           data.table(Month = rep(200005, 3), Firm = rep(2, 3), Rt = rnorm(3)))
Firm3 <- rbind(data.table(Month = rep(200001, 3), Firm = rep(3, 3), Rt = rnorm(3)) ,data.table(Month = rep(200002, 6), Firm = rep(3, 6), Rt = rnorm(6)),
           data.table(Month = rep(200003, 5), Firm = rep(3, 5), Rt = rnorm(5)), data.table(Month = rep(200004, 5), Firm = rep(3, 5), Rt = rnorm(5)),
           data.table(Month = rep(200005, 2), Firm = rep(3, 2), Rt = rnorm(2)))

DT <- rbind(Firm1, Firm2, Firm3)

DT[, Mar := rnorm(50)]
```

Which gives

```
Month Firm          Rt          Mar
200001    1 -1.34767475  0.865598407
200001    1 -0.70741105 -0.782668556
200001    1  0.61342578  0.021440129
200002    1 -1.53156217  1.988291260
200002    1 -0.42512876 -0.384017585
...
```

In this example multiple 'Month' factors relate to daily observations. Each Firm has a varying number of daily observations in each Month.

What I would like to do is estimate the variance of the residual from a linear regression of Rt vs Mar. To do this on a monthly basis, I would use

```
DT[, var(lm(Rt ~ Mar)$residuals), by = c("Firm", "Month")]
```

Differing from the above, I'd like to do the same each Month, using the previous n Month's observations. A naive attempt might look like

```
DT[, var(lm(Rt ~ Mar)$residuals), by = c("Firm", Month[t : t-2])]
```

With a final output

```
Month Firm          Rt          Mar      resVariance
200001    1 -1.34767475  0.865598407  NA
200001    1 -0.70741105 -0.782668556  NA
200001    1  0.61342578  0.021440129  NA
200002    1 -1.53156217  1.988291260  NA
200002    1 -0.42512876 -0.384017585  NA
200002    1  1.06399050 -1.123293332  NA
200002    1 -1.59751358 -0.188190495  NA
200003    1  0.08854875  0.897471055  0.8745559
200003    1  0.37822085 -0.654418019  0.8745559
200003    1  1.07786336  1.665720591  0.8745559
200003    1  0.92820233 -1.983931767  0.8745559
200003    1 -0.43148095 -0.286302699  0.8745559
200004    1 -0.80384703 -0.927657523  0.841801
200004    1 -0.79383439  1.281582524  0.841801
...
```

Any suggestions with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Right now there's no easy way to access any/all rows from previous groups *while* working on the current group. I've added a new [FR #1278](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1278). Not sure when we'll come to it.

But I'll provide some pointers here on how I'd approach it (until then). For example, if we've to extract *all* the previous rows, we can do that with the help of `.BY` argument:

```
# returns the unique values of each group
DT[, print(.BY), by=.(Firm, Month)]
```

Using this, we can extract either just the rows until the previous group

```
cols = c("Firm", "Month")
DT[, seq_len(DT[.BY, on=cols, which=TRUE, mult="first"]-1L), by=c(cols)]
```

The above gives the row indices (corresponding to `DT`) of all rows until previous group.

Alternatively, we can extract up until the current group as:

```
DT[, seq_len(DT[.BY, on=cols, which=TRUE, mult="last"]), by=c(cols)]
```

Of course if you've to extract the rows of the previous 'k' groups, it gets a little tricky. But still, I think the idea is the same.. you'll want to extract the corresponding `Firm, Month` combinations of all those groups and perform a `join` while grouping to extract them...

Comment: Thank you @Arun. While a work around will take a little more thought, I appreciate your feedback. data.table 1.9.5 has been installed and I'm enjoying playing around with some of the new features.